# Good java resources for learning Java and Solr

Tags: java, solr

I am completely new to java and I am using Solr search server. It happens that I have to learn java in order to be able to customize Solr for my application.
Does anyone have a good suggestion where the best place to start is?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may not be needed to know Java to get working with Solr and use it, unless you want to check the actual codebase and want to modify it or add extensions.
There are lot of clients also available in Ruby, PHP to work with Solr, once you have the setup working.
In addition to books by @peter_budo, For Solr and its Configuration, you can also get started with [Solr Guide](http://www.lucidimagination.com/devzone/references/solr-guide) by Lucid Imagination. This will get you started.

Comment: I am going to design filters so that I need to learn java I think, what would be your suggestion?

Comment: yup, If you need to modify or add extensions you would need to know Java. Solr has a vast variation of Filters that you can choose before you start designing your own.

Comment: @Mersad, I guess Solr will most likely have filters to meet your _initial_ needs. Hope you are not in a rush :-)

Answer (score 2):

The question is very generic and it really depends on your background and your aspirations and also your organization :)

If you are a developer and want to modify Solr code then it will be better (though not mandatory) if you know a bit about Information Retrieval, so as a first step you should understand what an inverted index is, what are data structures used for inverted index, how are boolean queries evaluated, how the query formation tree looks like etc. This will not only make your understanding of Solr good but say tomorrow you have another search engine XYZ in the market you will quickly be able to adapt to that.

If you want to make a carrer in Solr Administration than for the moment books like Solr 3.1 Cookbook & Apache Solr 3 Enterprise Search Server (Note that these books will be applicabe in every scenario whether you are a user, developer or administrator)coupled with practical experience will matter most where you would be dealing with Memory Errors, Heap problems, trying various combinations of mergefactors, autocmmits etc.

Again as per your other question about Java, it again depends on your programming background, i.e whether you come from C++ or say Python and so on. If you are already a C++/C# programmer then Java would be a cakewalk for you. In that case just understand Solr a bit and start your coding instead of wasting your time on a java book (Again it will be good if you waste your time on Java book and learn java first and move sequentially to Solr, it depends on time that you have) If you are a Python or a Haskell programmer, you will have to learn Java. In this particular case Head First Java would be he best book to quickly come at speed with Java say in a week or 2 weeks at max and then you can start with Solr.

One more thing to add for learning Solr its just not Java, you will have to learn bit about servlet containers that you are using as well.

My last suggestion (IMHO), dont go about learning tools and API's, study the science and engineering behind those tools (as i mentioned about Information Retrieval) & languages (learn more about fundamental Algorithms & Data Structures independant of a language), then automatically whether it will be Solr or Sphinx, C++ or Java, they all all will become your slaves.

Answer (score 1):

More in detail [Apache Solr 3 Enterprise Search Server](http://www.packtpub.com/apache-solr-3-enterprise-search-server/book) or recipes (or problem-solution driven learning approach) [Apache Solr 3.1 Cookbook](http://www.packtpub.com/solr-3-1-enterprise-search-server-cookbook/book)

Answer (score 1):

Solr wiki resources page http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrResources is the best place to start.
Use also lucene/solr mailing lists if you have more questions.